# regex pattern to print particular instance of a number

Tags: python, regex

Below is my code which i am trying to get only the value 265 and I don't want 255 MT and 233.

```
import re 
string1 = "start news, having 255 MT, 233 and 265"
price_find = re.findall(r'^\d{3}\s[A-Z]{2}|\d{3}', string1)
print(price_find)
```

If i run this i'm getting both 255 and 265

```
['255', '233', '265']
```

But im trying to get the output as below:

```
['233', '265']
```

Comment: You are seemingly contradicting yourself. Please verify your description and clearly indicate what should and should not be matched.

Comment: The question is not clear but perhaps you're looking for `\b\d{3}\b(?!\s[A-Z]{2}\b)`?

Comment: You don't want `233` but you are trying to capture the output `233`??

Comment: Using re.findall it should be like this without the anchor `^` and a capture group around the 3 digits after the pipe `\d{3}\s[A-Z]{2}|(\d{3})` but note that just matching 3 digits without boundaries can give you partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a regex issue. Collect all the numbers and use indexing:

```py
import re 
string1 = "start news, having 255 MT, 233 and 265"
price_find = re.findall(r'\d+', string1)
print(price_find[0])  # first,  255
print(price_find[-1]) # last,   265
print(price_find[1])  # second, 233
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##Zc2xCsIwEMbxvU/x0Q5tMYpJqFsfwc1NRUKT2kCbliQoPn1MVHDodnf8@N/y8sNseAh6WmbrYRUy5602d4oWufMiHo16OoJBPOIZrGlwPBEwziGMBDs0ebZY3albr@PexsYuTWIcK1te5KYk@CXrBI2v/vy8v9ZAgV5b5wlSfW22NKICo/iQ9HFt6LfjVDcbSZIJ4Q0).

Answer (score 0):

just use the following regex:

```
price_find = re.findall(r'\d{3}(?!\sMT)', string1)
```